# Failed to resolve assembly: 'ImageCircle.Forms'

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I copied my project to run on mac but I can not do the build because it caused this problem someone could help me solve:

```
Failed to resolve assembly: 'Image.Circle.Forms.Plugin.Abstrations, Versions = 0,0,0,0 Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = null'
```

Comment: Clean and Rebuild? Deleting bin & obj files?

Answer (score -1):

Have you added the reference through the Nuget or directly?
Could you try to remove that reference and add it again with the Nuget Manager?